# Linux R server (Shiny): Install Windows binaries

Tags: r, linux, shiny, shiny-server, cran

Is there some way to install a (modified) R package (zip Windows binaries) on a linux machine (using command line) running Rserver + Shiny ?

Comment: Is there any way you can use a source package (.tar.gz) instead?

Comment: Sadly not. I'm not responsible of the R packaging...